# How to use static resource image in visualforce email template editor

Tags: visualforce, email-template, static-resources

I am using a public `site` and a public `static resource` to add images to a `visualforce` email template.

But when I use this code:

```
<img src="http://example.force.com/email/{!$Resource.logo_300}" height="50" />
```

The image appears in the email when actually sent, but not in the Visualforce email editor preview.

How can I get it to work in the Visualforce email editor?